# how to use execv to execute ffmpeg ingest rtmp stream

Tags: ffmpeg, timeout, rtmp, execv

I can execute the follow command in linux successfully:

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://42.62.95.48/live?vhost=hls/livestream timeout=2" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f flv -y rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/hd
```

but it does not worked in the follow code:

```
std::vector<std::string> params;
params.push_back("/objs/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg");
params.push_back("-i");
params.push_back("\"rtmp://ossrs.net/live/livestream timeout=3\"");
params.push_back("-vcodec");
params.push_back("copy");
params.push_back("-acodec");
params.push_back("copy");
params.push_back("-f");
params.push_back("flv");
params.push_back("-y");
params.push_back("rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/hd");

char** charpv_params = new char*[params.size() + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < (int)params.size(); i++) {
    std::string& p = params[i];
    charpv_params[i] = (char*)p.data();
}

charpv_params[params.size()] = NULL;
execv("/objs/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg", charpv_params)
```

anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

If an `execv` call fails, the `errno` variable is set to the error code describing the problem. You should be able to print that error, either with the `perror` function or just by printing the number and looking it up in a [table](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html).

For what it's worth, when I tried to run your code, I got error number 2, for file not found - I don't have ffmpeg at `/objs/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg`, I have it at `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`.